# Как изменять url с помощью jquery? Надо добавить к адресу #word (можно ссылкой), но

Tags: url, jquery

На ссылке у меня сам адрес на статью, которая подгружается ajaxом, и стоит `preventDefault();`. Так вот, если я каждой статье дам айдишник с айди статей, и чтобы он добавлялся в адресную строку, например `site.com/?p=4` (где `p=4` это и есть айдишник), а по нему будет открываться модальное окно с этой статьей, если человек перешел по ссылке с другого сайта

Answer (score 1):

примерно так:

history.pushState(null,null,'/p=4#word');

хорошая статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/